# Mobile responsive css columns with image and text merging into one column

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I've been working on this website for quite some time, and the only thing that haven't figured out yet is to get my two columns to merge into one column when viewed on a mobile phone (desktop and tablet looks best with two columns).

My site is at jordanmiller.newbedesign.com and should be able to view the source code and css file that same way, but I'll past my CSS code here just in case. I've been looking at several tutorials on the subject, but when I try to implement the code, either I cannot figure out how to integrate it, or it simply doesn't appear to have an effect.

I realize I'm novice, so I'm sure it's something with my code (sorry if it's a mess), so I'm hoping I could get some insight/suggestions. Thank you in advance!

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em) {
 .leftColumn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 18.75em;
 }
 
 .rightColumn {
  margin-right: 19.53em;
 }
 
a {
    color: #418bf0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav#navigation {
    position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 1em; /* 15px */
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}

nav#navigation a {
    color: #363b47;
    padding-left: 1em; /* 5px */
    padding-right: 1em; /* 5px */
}

nav#navigation a:hover {
    color: #418bf0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav#navigation a.current {
    color: #418bf0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.contact {
 padding-left: 3%; /* 10px */
 padding-right: 3%; /* 10px */
}

a#contactleft {
 padding-left: 0%;
 padding-right: 3%; /* 10px */
}

}

html {
 margin: 0;
 margin-top: 5%;
 padding: 0%;
}

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #464c5c;
    font-size: .875em; /* 14px */
    line-height: 1.25em; /* 20px */
}

.columnsContainer {
 border: 0;
 padding: 1.25em;
 margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.leftColumn {
 position: relative;
 margin: .5em;
}

.rightColumn {
 border: 0;
 padding: 1.25em;
}

a {
    color: #418bf0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 34%; /* 110px */
    height: 8%; /* 27px */
    position: relative;
 float: left;
    left: 4%;
}

div#wrap {
    width: 100%; /* 726px */
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 3%; /* 10px */
}

nav#navigation {
    position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 1em; /* 15px */
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}

nav#navigation a {
    color: #363b47;
    padding-left: 1em; /* 5px */
    padding-right: 1em; /* 5px */
}

nav#navigation a:hover {
    color: #418bf0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav#navigation a.current {
    color: #418bf0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div#footer {
    position: relative;
    top: 4%; /* 15px */
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 3%; /* 10px */
 clear: both;
}

div.main {
 border: 0;
 padding: 5%; /* 10px */
}

div#profileimg {
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 40%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 Padding-bottom: 3%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

a.contact {
 padding-left: 3%; /* 10px */
 padding-right: 3%; /* 10px */
}

a#contactleft {
 padding-left: 0%;
 padding-right: 3%; /* 10px */
}

div#bio {
 vertical-align: top;
 float: right;
 width: 60%;
 position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are along the right lines, but there are a couple of things to correct. Your media queries should appear in the stylesheet **after** the CSS for the default setup, not at the top of the stylesheet. This is because CSS that comes later will override any CSS settings for the same selector that appeared previously; the last CSS to appear in the sylesheet is used where there is a conflict.

In your case, near the bottom of the CSS you have:
    .leftColumn {
        position: relative;
        margin: .5em;
    }
which (since it is not in a media query) applies at all screen widths. So this relative positioning will override the absolute positioning you gave to .leftColum for wider screens higher up, in your media query.

Remember also that for absolute positioning to work on an element, you must give its parent div (or something higher up the tree) a non-default position (usually relative). The rule is, an absolutely positioned element is positioned "relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static" (static being the default). So if your container is columnsContainer (the url you give doesn't seem to have the relevant code on it - only give a url if it shows the actual problem in question!) then set that to position: relative.

Also your left column is actually going to appear on the right side ofthe page, as the query specifies right: 0; and then positions the right column to the left of that. I think you mean:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em) {
.leftColumn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 18.75em;
    }
.rightColumn {
    margin-left: 19.53em;
}
```

But lovely to see someone using em units in the media query breakpoints, instead of px units. Many experienced responsive developers don't follow that!